# Base change for vector spaces

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

For two distinct prime numbers $l$ and $l'$ let $V_l$ (resp. $V_{l'}$) be finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}_l$ (resp. $\mathbb{Q}_{l'}$).

Suppose when regarded as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces $V_l \cong V_{l'}$.

Is there always a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $V$ such $V_l \cong V \otimes \mathbb{Q}_l$ and $V_{l'} \cong V \otimes \mathbb{Q}_{l'}$?

Does the answer generalize to the case of not just two but infinitely many primes?

Comment: The isomorphism class of a ${\mathbb Q}$-vector space is determined by its dimension.  Because ${\mathbb Q}_l$ and ${\mathbb Q}_{l'}$ have the same (infinite) dimension over ${\mathbb Q}$, so do $V_l$ and $V_{l'}$  and both are isomorphic to ${\mathbb Q}_l$ and ${\mathbb Q}_{l'}$ (unless one of them is zero-dimensional).  So your hypothesis holds even before you assume it, and your conclusion is true with $V={\mathbb Q}$ (or any other finite dimensional ${\mathbb Q}$-vector space you might prefer).